# What would be the gun's damage per click?

Tags: probability

There is a gun with 1246.6 damage per bullet. 
It shoots three bullets every click.
But also each bullet has a 90% chance of spawning one more, so the final number of bullets would lie between 3 and 6.
So I'm wondering, the average damage per click?

Comment: Do each of the spawned bullets also have a $90\%$ chance of spawning one more?

Comment: No, only the bullets that have been initially fired can spawn one more.

Comment: So there's a 100% chance of hitting the target?!?!?!?

Comment: What?  What is the meaning of 1246.6 damage?   What does it mean if a bullet does 1246.6 damage to me?  What does it mean for a bullet to spawn a bullet?  I suspect that you are trying to describe a video game mechanic, but I have no idea how to interpret your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since spawned bullets don't spawn again, each original bullet is essentially (on average) $1.9$ bullets. So the expected (average) damage for a three bullet click is
$$
3 \times 1.9 \times 1246.6 .
$$

(The five significant digit precision in the damage per bullet seems unrealistic to me.)

Comment: Each bullet has a 90% chance. This means that different cases are possible, one where None of the bullets split, three where only two of them do and one where all three of them split.

Comment: @Mayonnaise The "$1.9$ bullets per bullet" takes into account all the possibilities, with the right probabilities. You don't have to work out each case separately.